# How to remove the margin/padding of an image?

Tags: html, css, image

I am creating a website and am placing an image on the homepage that should cover the entire page. Despite multiple Google searches and attempts, there is still a margin/padding on the top, left, right, and bottom.

Here is my current CSS code for the image:

```
.tiger-woods-img {
    display: block;
    line-height: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is how the webpage looks with this code (it is hard to see since the background is white, but there is a small margin/padding on all sides of the image):
[image: webpage]

I tried to include the following code:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

And it worked, but it messed up my navbar.

Is there another solution for this issue?

Comment: can you provide your `html`  code or some link to codepen?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this quite a lot and what I have found to work 75% of the time is to do this:

```css
image#id {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

You could try this. As for messing up your navbar, I'm sorry about that. You could consider changing your layout altogether (I can think of a way to force the navbar to stay put with `flexbox`).

[Edit] How about this: create a `<div>` in the spot where you want the image, then set the image as the `background-image` of this particular div? Take a look at the result of this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url(https://st.focusedcollection.com/14026668/i/1800/focused_181856282-stock-photo-spain-menorca-field-poppy-flowers.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[One more edit] Do you specify `box-sizing`? It would really help to set annoying boxes with

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It would be nice if you can drop a link to your code so it's easier to see how to assist you.